# Plugin isn't working in Magento2 local host

Tags: magento2, plugin, localhost, after-plugin

My very basic plugin is not working and i can't understand why. I'm very new to Magento 2 so it's probably something simple. The Plugin is suppose to display "Too expensive" or "too cheap" on all products.

di.xml code

```
<config>
<type name="Inchoo\Custom\Plugins">
    <plugin name="Product" type="Inchoo\Custom\Plugins\Product" sortOrder="1" 
disabled="false"/>
</type>
</config>
```

Product.php code

```
<?php

namespace Inchoo\Custom\Plugins;

Class Product {
public function aftergetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $name) 
{
  $price = $product ->getData(key:'price');
  if ($price < 60 ) {
    $name .= " So cheap" ;
}
  else {
    $name .= " Too expensive";
}

  return $name;
    }
}
```

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance, Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You di.xml file should have below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="InchooProduct" type="Inchoo\Custom\Plugins\Product" sortOrder="1" 
disabled="false"/>
</type>
</config>
```

- Type name: A class, interface, or virtual type, which is observed by
  a plugin.
- Plugin name: A plugin name.
- Plugin type: The name of a plugin’s    class or virtual type.
- Plugin sortOrder: Order, in which the plugins    calling the same
  method are to be executed.
- Plugin disabled: This    attribute defines whether the plugin is
  enabled or not.       disabled="true" defines the plugin is disabled.

change your function name `aftergetName` to `afterGetName`

Comment: All sorted, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The method name needs to be `afterGetName`. Also `getData(key:'price')` is wrong. You can either use `->getData('price')` or `->getPrice()`.

```
<?php

namespace Inchoo\Custom\Plugins;

Class Product {
public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $name) 
{
  $price = $product->getPrice();
  if ($price < 60 ) {
    $name .= " So cheap" ;
}
  else {
    $name .= " Too expensive";
}

  return $name;
    }
}
```

See if that works.

Comment: updated my answer .

Comment: Cheers, all sorted now. Thanks for your help!